Extracting data from a Json file in React
I am trying to map over these data:
{
  "id": "01hv7e9pqyr726z7s13hskrz3d",
  "ground_truth_labels": [
    "motion",
    "shaken",
    "stationary_upright",
    "stationary_not_upright"
  ],
  "name": "Asset tracking",
  "description": "Dataset for the Asset Tracking get started project",
  "created": "2024-04-11T20:41:28",
  "modified": "2024-04-11T20:42:55",
  "handler": {
    "kind": "VespucciInertialTimeseries",
    "version": "v1alpha1"
  },
  "selector_labels": {
    "test_label": "abcd",
    "chunk_device_name": "STEVAL-MKBOXPRO",
    "another_test_label": "efgh",
    "chunk_firmware_name": "FP-SNS-DATALOG2_Datalog2",
    "chunk_device_os_name": "AzureRTOS",
    "chunk_firmware_alias": "STBOX_PRO_001",
    "chunk_firmware_version": "1.2.1|1.1.0",
    "chunk_device_architecture": "ARM Cortex-M33",
    "chunk_firmware_part_number": "STEVAL-MKBOXPRO",
    "chunk_sensor_lsm6dsv16x_acc": "true"
  },
  "chunks": [
    {
      "id": "01hv7echctxcdnj362wgm7et5g",
      "ground_truth": "motion",
      "files": [
        {
          "blob": {
            "id": "hmyiqflc2ofmcxacyxfavgxsksajlt2sdqqbayk4uyilxxdneybq====",
            "size": 9482
          },
          "relative_path": "motion/20230905_12_37_33_0_hmyiqflc.csv",
          "metadata": {}
        }
      ],
      "source_blob": {
        "id": "v5dsifboxljuvpzde24ltvqor5zs2grzvhxa2ocdjhrqehvgcseq====",
        "size": 85648
      },
      "selector_labels": {
        "device_name": "STEVAL-MKBOXPRO",
        "firmware_name": "FP-SNS-DATALOG2_Datalog2",
        "device_os_name": "AzureRTOS",
        "firmware_alias": "STBOX_PRO_001",
        "firmware_version": "1.2.1",
        "device_architecture": "ARM Cortex-M33",
        "firmware_part_number": "STEVAL-MKBOXPRO",
        "sensor_lsm6dsv16x_acc": "true"
      },
      "created": "2024-04-11T20:43:01",
      "modified": "2024-04-11T20:43:01",
      "metadata": {
        "device": {
          "metadata": {},
          "components": [
            {
              "name": "lsm6dsv16x_acc",
              "type": "acc",
              "config": {
                "fs": {
                  "unit": "g",
                  "value": 16
                },
                "odr": {
                  "unit": "Hz",
                  "value": 30
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "end_time": "2000-01-01T00:07:25.237000+00:00",
        "start_time": "2000-01-01T00:07:17.241000+00:00",
        "end_time_ts": "199.172728",
        "split_index": 0,
        "firmware_info": {
          "name": "firmware_info",
          "alias": "STBOX_PRO_001",
          "c_type": 2,
          "fw_url": "https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/fp-sns-datalog2",
          "fw_name": "FP-SNS-DATALOG2_Datalog2",
          "device_url": "www.st.com/sensortileboxpro",
          "fw_version": "1.2.1",
          "mac_address": "ec:12:25:8:63:a",
          "part_number": "STEVAL-MKBOXPRO"
        },
        "start_time_ts": "191.257942",
        "source_metadata": {
          "name": "20230905_12_37_33",
          "tags": [
            {
              "e": true,
              "l": "stationary_upright",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:04:22.206Z"
            },
            {
              "e": false,
              "l": "stationary_upright",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:04:53.417Z"
            },
            {
              "e": true,
              "l": "stationary_not_upright",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:05:08.007Z"
            },
            {
              "e": false,
              "l": "stationary_not_upright",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:05:18.255Z"
            },
            {
              "e": true,
              "l": "motion",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:05:44.136Z"
            },
            {
              "e": false,
              "l": "motion",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:05:51.008Z"
            },
            {
              "e": true,
              "l": "motion",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:05:58.240Z"
            },
            {
              "e": false,
              "l": "motion",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:06:01.349Z"
            },
            {
              "e": true,
              "l": "stationary_not_upright",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:06:03.977Z"
            },
            {
              "e": false,
              "l": "stationary_not_upright",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:06:16.088Z"
            },
            {
              "e": true,
              "l": "motion",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:06:17.936Z"
            },
            {
              "e": false,
              "l": "motion",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:06:30.517Z"
            },
            {
              "e": true,
              "l": "stationary_not_upright",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:06:32.418Z"
            },
            {
              "e": false,
              "l": "stationary_not_upright",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:06:43.253Z"
            },
            {
              "e": true,
              "l": "motion",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:06:46.517Z"
            },
            {
              "e": false,
              "l": "motion",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:06:54.735Z"
            },
            {
              "e": true,
              "l": "stationary_not_upright",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:07:05.027Z"
            },
            {
              "e": false,
              "l": "stationary_not_upright",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:07:15.489Z"
            },
            {
              "e": true,
              "l": "motion",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:07:17.241Z"
            },
            {
              "e": false,
              "l": "motion",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:07:25.237Z"
            },
            {
              "e": true,
              "l": "motion",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:07:31.586Z"
            },
            {
              "e": false,
              "l": "motion",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:07:56.719Z"
            },
            {
              "e": true,
              "l": "shaken",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:08:01.979Z"
            },
            {
              "e": false,
              "l": "shaken",
              "ta": "2000-01-01T00:08:35.390Z"
            }
          ],
          "uuid": "34a55669-0f31-47f0-8b66-182412eb937b",
          "c_type": 2,
          "data_ext": ".dat",
          "data_fmt": "HSD_2.0.0",
          "end_time": "2000-01-01T00:08:38.524Z",
          "interface": 1,
          "start_time": "2000-01-01T00:04:06.000Z",
          "description": "20230905_12_37_33",
          "schema_version": "2.0.0"
        },
        "device_information": {
          "name": "DeviceInformation",
          "model": "STEVAL-MKBOXPRO",
          "osName": "AzureRTOS",
          "swVersion": "1.2.0",
          "totalMemory": 784,
          "manufacturer": "STMicroelectronics",
          "totalStorage": 4,
          "processorArchitecture": "ARM Cortex-M33",
          "processorManufacturer": "STMicroelectronics"
        }
      }

A chunk has a lot of ids and I want to map over them inside the MlcAccordion component:
import { useState, ReactNode } from 'react'
import arrowExpandIcon from '@/assets/arrowExpand.svg'
import filterFillIcon from '@/assets/filter-fill.svg'
import { SimpleCheckbox } from '@/shareable-components/input/checkbox/simple-checkbox/SimpleCheckbox'
import { RadioButton } from '@/shareable-components/input/radio/RadioButton'
import data from '@/assets/edit-mlc-schemas/LSM6DSO32X.json'
import { FilterButton } from '@/shareable-components/button/filter-button/FilterButton'
import { MlcTable } from '@/shareable-components/data-display/mlc-table/MlcTable'
import { Chip } from '@/shareable-components/data-display/chip/Chip'
import dataEntries from '@/assets/edit-mlc-schemas/dataset-asset-tracking-formatted.json'

export type TableHeadCell = { id: string; label: string }
export type TableHead = ReadonlyArray<TableHeadCell>
export type DataRow = Record<string, ReactNode>

export interface MlcAccordionProps {
  accordionTitle: string
  accordionHead: TableHead
  checkboxLabels: string[]
  radioButtonsLabels: string[]
  onSubmit: () => void
  onFormDataChange: (newData: Partial<FormData>) => void
}

export function MlcAccordion({
  accordionTitle,
  accordionHead,
  checkboxLabels,
  onSubmit,
}: MlcAccordionProps) {
  const [selectedCheckbox, setSelectedCheckbox] = useState<string>('')
  const [selectedRadio, setSelectedRadio] = useState<string>('')
  const [expandTable, setExpandTable] = useState(true)

  const toggleExpandTable = () => setExpandTable((toggle) => !toggle)

  const handleCheckboxChange = (label: string) => {
    setSelectedCheckbox(label)
  }

  const handleRadioChange = (label: string) => {
    setSelectedRadio(label)
  }

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    const formData = {
      selectedCheckbox,
      selectedRadio,
    }
    console.log('Form Data:', formData)
    onSubmit()
  }

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    // Add your button click logic here
    console.log('Button clicked')
  }

  const renderCheckboxes = () => {
    return checkboxLabels.map((label, index) => (
      <div key={index} className="mt-2">
        <SimpleCheckbox
          label={label}
          handleCheck={() => handleCheckboxChange(label)}
          checked={selectedCheckbox === label}
        />
      </div>
    ))
  }

  const renderRadio = () => {
    return data.mlc_odr.map((label, index) => (
      <div key={index} className="mt-2">
        <RadioButton
          label={label}
          groupName="mlc_radio_group" // Set an appropriate group name
          checked={selectedRadio === label}
          onChange={() => handleRadioChange(label)}
        />
      </div>
    ))
  }

  const renderAccordionHead = () => {
    const buildheadRow = () => {
      return accordionHead.map((h, index) => (
        <th
          key={index}
          data-testid="table-head-cell"
          className={`text-start hover:border-light-blue cursor-pointer text-dark-blue mx-1 border-b-2 border-gray-2 font-light text-[17px]`}
        >
          <button>{h.label}</button>
        </th>
      ))
    }

    return (
      <tr data-testid="table-head-row" className="">
        {accordionHead.length ? (
          buildheadRow()
        ) : (
          <th
            data-testid="table-head-cell"
            className="lg:px-0 text-gray-7 align-middle pt-3 pb-6 text-[15px]font-bold text-center hidden lg:table-cell"
          >
            No data available
          </th>
        )}
      </tr>
    )
  }

  const hardcodedData = [
    {
      acquisition: '20240212_12_44_00_0',
      file: '20240212_12_44_00_0_5svgvtr3.csv',
      updated: 'Fri Mar 01 2024 14:38:50',
      time: { start: '1,575 sec', stop: '1,575 sec', duration: '1,575 sec' },
      classes: 'shaken',
      board: 'SensorTile.box PRO',
      sensors: {
        accelerometer: {
          odr: '480.0 Hz',
          fs: '4.0 g'
        },
        gyroscope: {
          odr: '335.0 Hz',
          fs: '4.8 g'
        }
      },
      id: '1',
    },
    {
      acquisition: '20240212_12_44_00_0',
      file: '20240212_15_44_00_0_5svgvtr3.csv',
      updated: 'Fri Mar 01 2024 14:38:50',
      time: { start: '1,575 sec', stop: '1,575 sec', duration: '1,575 sec' },
      classes: 'stationary_not_upright',
      board: 'SensorTile.box PRO',
      sensors: {
        accelerometer: {
          odr: '480.0 Hz',
          fs: '4.0 g'
        },
        gyroscope: {
          odr: '334.2 Hz',
          fs: '4.8 g'
        }
      },
      id: '2',
    },
    // Add more objects as needed
  ]

  return (
    <div
      data-testid="accordion-body"
      className="grid mt-10 w-full overflow-x-auto border-2 rounded-lg border-gray-2"
    >
      <div data-testid="table-heading" className="lg:flex items-stretch">
        <div data-testid="table-left-section" className="min-w-fit lg:w-[90%]">
          <div data-testid="view-buttons" className="flex justify-start">
            <button
              data-testid="collapse-heading-button"
              className="flex items-center w-full p-5 font-bold text-light-text-primary"
              onClick={toggleExpandTable}
            >
              <img
                data-testid="collapse-heading-button-img"
                src={arrowExpandIcon}
                className={`transform ${expandTable ? 'rotate-180' : ''} mr-8`}
              />
              <span data-testid="collapse-heading-button-text">{accordionTitle}</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className={`${expandTable ? '' : 'hidden'}`}></div>
      <div data-testid="table-container" className={`${expandTable ? '' : 'hidden'} p-5 mb-5`}>
        <table data-testid="table-container" className="justify-evenly w-full">
          <thead data-testid="table-head">{renderAccordionHead()}</thead>
        </table>
        <p className="mt-4 text-gray">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
          ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>
        <p className="mt-10 text-gray font-bold">1. Choose used sensors:</p>
        <div className="flex space-x-10">{renderCheckboxes()}</div>
        <p className="mt-10 text-gray font-bold">2. Select Machine Learning Core ODR:</p>
        <div className="flex space-x-10">{renderRadio()}</div>
        <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
        <p className="mt-10 text-gray font-bold">3. Select Acquisition Files:</p>
        <div data-testid="view-button" className="flex justify-start mt-2 mb-4">
          <FilterButton icon={filterFillIcon} label="Filters" onClick={handleButtonClick} />
        </div>
        <MlcTable
          tableHead={[
            { id: 'acquisition', label: 'Acquisition' },
            { id: 'fileName', label: 'File Name' },
            { id: 'updated', label: 'Updated' },
            { id: 'times', label: 'Times' },
            { id: 'classes', label: 'Classes' },
            { id: 'board', label: 'Board' },
            { id: 'sensors', label: 'Sensors' },
          ]}
          tableRows={hardcodedData.map((model) => ({
            acquisition: model.acquisition,
            fileName: (
              <div className="whitespace-pre-line">
                <div className="truncate" style={{ lineHeight: '1.8' }}>
                  {model.file.split('.')[0]}
                </div>
                <div className="truncate" style={{ lineHeight: '1.8' }}>
                  {model.file.split('.')[1]}
                </div>
              </div>
            ),
            updated: model.updated, // Added the updated string here
            times: (
              <div className="mt-2 mb-2">
                <p>
                  <strong>Start:</strong> {model.time.start}
                </p>
                <p>
                  <strong>Stop:</strong>: {model.time.stop}
                </p>
                <p>
                  <strong>Duration:</strong> {model.time.duration}
                </p>
              </div>
            ),
            classes: model.classes,
            board: (
              <div className="flex">
                <Chip color="bg-pink" label={`${model.board}`} />
              </div>
            ),
            sensors: (
              <div className='my-2'>
                <div>
                  <p className="font-bold">Accelerometer</p>
                  <ul className="list-disc">
                    <li className="mb-[-5px] mt-[-5px]">
                      <strong>ODR: </strong>{model.sensors.accelerometer.odr}
                    </li>
                    <li className="mb-[-5px]">
                      <strong>FS: </strong>{model.sensors.accelerometer.fs}
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <hr className="my-1 border-dashed border-gray-2" />
                <div>
                  <p className="font-bold">Gyroscope</p>
                  <ul className="list-disc">
                    <li className="mb-[-5px] mt-[-5px]">
                      <strong>ODR: </strong>{model.sensors.gyroscope.odr}
                    </li>
                    <li className="mb-[-5px]">
                      <strong>FS: </strong>{model.sensors.gyroscope.fs}
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            ),
          }))}
        />
      </div>
      <div className={`${expandTable ? '' : 'hidden'} mx-1 mb-5`}></div>
    </div>
  )
}

The data are harcoded for now and I am passing them inside the tableRows prop: Now the problem is that when I try to pass the dataEntries inside the map it gives me a warning above map:
Property 'map' does not exist on type '{ id: string; ground_truth_labels: string[]; name: string; description: string; created: string; modified: string; handler: { kind: string; version: string; }; selector_labels: { test_label: string; ... 8 more ...; chunk_sensor_lsm6dsv16x_acc: string; }; chunks: ({ ...; } | { ...; })[]; metadata: {}; }'.ts(2339)
any
tableRows={dataEntries.map((model) => ({
            acquisition: model.acquisition,
            fileName: (
              <div className="whitespace-pre-line">
                <div className="truncate" style={{ lineHeight: '1.8' }}>
                  {model.file.split('.')[0]}
                </div>
                <div className="truncate" style={{ lineHeight: '1.8' }}>
                  {model.file.split('.')[1]}
                </div>
              </div>
            ),
            updated: model.updated, // Added the updated string here
            times: (
              <div className="mt-2 mb-2">
                <p>
                  <strong>Start:</strong> {model.time.start}
                </p>
                <p>
                  <strong>Stop:</strong>: {model.time.stop}
                </p>
                <p>
                  <strong>Duration:</strong> {model.time.duration}
                </p>
              </div>
            ),
            classes: model.classes,
            board: (
              <div className="flex">
                <Chip color="bg-pink" label={`${model.board}`} />
              </div>
            ),
            sensors: (
              <div className='my-2'>
                <div>
                  <p className="font-bold">Accelerometer</p>
                  <ul className="list-disc">
                    <li className="mb-[-5px] mt-[-5px]">
                      <strong>ODR: </strong>{model.sensors.accelerometer.odr}
                    </li>
                    <li className="mb-[-5px]">
                      <strong>FS: </strong>{model.sensors.accelerometer.fs}
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
                <hr className="my-1 border-dashed border-gray-2" />
                <div>
                  <p className="font-bold">Gyroscope</p>
                  <ul className="list-disc">
                    <li className="mb-[-5px] mt-[-5px]">
                      <strong>ODR: </strong>{model.sensors.gyroscope.odr}
                    </li>
                    <li className="mb-[-5px]">
                      <strong>FS: </strong>{model.sensors.gyroscope.fs}
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            ),
          }))}


dataEntries is an object not an array

What should I do then? Change the json?

I don't know how to fix this

If you make your question a bit clearer it will be easier to answer. You posted an object at the top, then you also have hardcodedData which is an array not an object, in one snippet you map over hardcodedData and then in another you map over dataEntries but don't say what shape that is (I guess that one is where the error is since hardcodedData is an actual array and should have that error so not sure why it's also shown)
